# asp.net clear row selection for Multiple Grid with Single Button Click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi Friends i have created a single asp.net page(c#) with multiple grid view to display records. I have multiple command button to show records in these grid.
I am using single button to clear the row selection in grid but it is not working. 
Please help me...

```
 protected void btnClearGridSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridViewSearch.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridViewState.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridViewDistrict.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridViewType.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
 if (GridView1.Visible == true)
 {
 GridViewEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }

 }
```

//---------------------updating my question with new problem-------------
Now i am able to to clear the selection from row but facing new problem.......When i am clicking on show(to show results state wise) button  it is showing results and also clearing the selection when clicking on clear selection button with no problems....but when i click on another show button(to show results district wise) to show results it is showing results but when i select the row and click on clear selection button it is showing both grid with records......please help how to hide state Grid when i am Clicking on Clear Selection Button while using District grid......i am posting the code which i am using on Button Click....

.......clear selection....Button click:

```
 protected void btnClearGridSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
 GridViewSearch.SelectedIndex = -1;
 GridViewState.SelectedIndex = -1;
 GridViewDistrict.SelectedIndex = -1;
 GridViewType.SelectedIndex = -1;
 GridViewEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1;
 }
```

.......State Grid....Button click:

```
 protected void btnState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 GridView1.Visible = false;
 //GridViewState.Visible = true;
 GridViewDistrict.Visible = false;
 GridViewSearch.Visible = false;
 GridViewType.Visible = false;
 GridViewEmployee.Visible = false;
 btnClearGridSelection.Visible = true;
 string d2 = ddlState.Text;
 string strquery = "select * from  tblAsset2 where v_State=@d2";
 if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
 con.Close();
 }
 con.Open();
 try
 {
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", d2);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 GridViewState.DataSource = ds;
 GridViewState.DataBind();
 int rowCount = GridViewState.Rows.Count;
 if (rowCount <= 0)
 {
 Label67.Visible = true;
 GridViewState.Visible = false;
 Label67.Text = "Sorry!....Records not found.";
 }
 else
 {
 GridViewState.Visible = true;
 Label67.Visible = false;
 }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write(ex);
 }
 finally
 {
 con.Close();
 }
 }
```

....................District Grid....Button click:

```
 protected void btnDistrict_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 GridView1.Visible = false;
 GridViewDistrict.Visible = false;
 //GridViewDistrict.Visible = true;
 GridViewSearch.Visible = false;
 GridViewType.Visible = false;
 GridViewEmployee.Visible = false;
 btnClearGridSelection.Visible = true;
 string d2 = ddlDistrict.Text;
 string strquery = "select * from  tblAsset2 where v_District=@d2";
 if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
 con.Close();
 }
 con.Open();
 try
 {
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", d2);
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 GridViewDistrict.DataSource = ds;
 GridViewDistrict.DataBind();
 int rowCount = GridViewDistrict.Rows.Count;
 if (rowCount <= 0)
 {
 Label67.Visible = true;
 GridViewDistrict.Visible = false;
 Label67.Text = "Sorry!....Records not found.";
 }
 else
 {
 GridViewDistrict.Visible = true;
 Label67.Visible = false;
 }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write(ex);
 }
 finally
 {
 con.Close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Is the grid in Edit or View mode?

Comment: thanks Cristian for the quick reply. grid is in view mode.  Now i have changed the above code like following :    GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;   
     GridViewSearch.SelectedIndex = -1;   
     GridViewState.SelectedIndex = -1;   
     GridViewDistrict.SelectedIndex = -1;    
     GridViewType.SelectedIndex = -1;    
     GridViewEmployee.SelectedIndex = -1;                                                    ................it is clearing the selection but with new problem.............. now i am facing another problem ... i will add the code and details of the problem

Comment: i have updated my question . would it be possible to you to review it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem and it may help someone else so i am posting it..  i have written wrong line:- GridViewState.Visible = true; // i have commented this line and error gone

```
 protected void GridViewState_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
 GridViewState.Visible = true; // i have commented this line and error gone

 }
```